# Combining while loop and onclick function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, onclick, boolean

I am trying to make new squares appear as soon as the original square is clicked. With this code, you have to reload each time to make a new square appear. Is there a way to combine a while loop with a boolean value with the onclick function in javascript to make this happen ? Here's the code:

```js
var starttime = new Date().getTime();
var topposition = Math.random() * 650;
var leftposition = Math.random() * 650;
var colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "brown", "black", "purple", "orange"];
document.getElementById('shape').style.backgroundColor = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
document.getElementById('shape').style.top = topposition + "px";
document.getElementById('shape').style.left = leftposition + "px";

document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
  var endtime = new Date().getTime();
  var timetaken = (endtime - starttime) / 1000;
  document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = +timetaken + " seconds";
}
```

```css
#shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Do not use a while loop to check something. It will block the page.

Comment: "*I am trying to make new squares appear as soon as the original square is clicked.*" why do you want to avoid standard click event listener(s)?

Comment: You should create a function() with your JS logic and call it with a Event. Like onlick for exemple https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick. In your exemple the logic is just called ONCE the page is loaded and just ONE time.

Comment: I am just new to coding. So, I create a function that runs when the original square is clicked, and the instructions of that function is to make a new square? Is there a way of keeping 1 element that just moves each time you click it, changes colour, and starts the timer simultaneously? I think that I would have to remove "display = none" from the code, but since the random positions are inside a variable, it won't move. The timer will also just add the total time instead of resetting, which is why I thought of a loop to make it restart each time, and to make the randomisation restart as well.

Comment: UPDATE: was able to get square to move and change colour each time it is clicked. However, the timer once again just combines the time. I suppose that this is because it starts as soon as the page is loaded, but I need it to start when the page is loaded at first AND to restart when the square is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I destroy the shape on click and create a new one. I also get and display a new time.

```js
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var positionFactor = 650;
var colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "brown", "black", "purple", "orange"];
var shapeHolder = document.getElementById("shape-holder");
makeSquare();

function makeSquare ()
{
    starttime = new Date().getTime();
    var topposition = Math.random() * positionFactor;
    var leftposition = Math.random() * positionFactor;
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.backgroundColor = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
    square.style.top = topposition + "px";
    square.style.left = leftposition + "px";
    square.id = "shape";
    shapeHolder.appendChild(square);
    square.onclick = function() 
    {
         var endtime = new Date().getTime();
         var timetaken = (endtime - starttime) / 1000;
         document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = +timetaken + " seconds";
         var square = document.getElementById("shape");
         square.parentElement.removeChild(square);
         makeSquare();
    }
}
```

```css
#shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#shape-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
<div id="shape-holder"></div>
```

Comment: Could also move the reassignment of starttime to the end of makeSquare so you aren't also timing that function, but that's for you to determine.

Comment: The main thing I think you missed in your example was that - as others have mentioned - you need to make a new square, or reposition/colour your original square when a click happens. The code you wrote outside of the onclick function will only happen once, it won't re-run when the square is clicked.

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest I've gotten to what I actually want. The only issue is, the function runs when you click anywhere in the shapeHolder node and not specifically on the square elements. Too bad JS doesn’t let us call variables/elements that are inside functions.

Comment: I have moved the onclick to the square / shape. If this has answered your question please accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have made it all right, Just few things needed to be changed.
First make some function so that you can use them again when you need because in this case you want to reset time and color of shape and all that right?

Herewith i am attaching the modified code my friend...

```html
 <html>

      <head>

        <title>javascript</title>

        <style type="text/css">
    
        #shape {

            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
            
        }
    
        </style>

     </head>

     <body>
    
       <p>Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
    
       <div id="shape"></div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          //all variables listed as global so that you access them whenever you need...
          var starttime,topposition,leftposition,colours;
          
          //for some reason...it is needed...
          let FirstTime = true;
          
          //init. function for reseting all the parameters like...starttime,position,color etc...
         
          function Initialize()
          {
            starttime = new Date().getTime();

            topposition = Math.random() * 650;

            leftposition = Math.random() * 650;

            colours = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "brown","black","purple","orange"];

            document.getElementById('shape').style.backgroundColor = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

            document.getElementById('shape').style.top = topposition + "px";

            document.getElementById('shape').style.left = leftposition + "px";
            
            //if it is not the first time...
            if(!FirstTime)
            {
              //it will also reset the display of id "shape"...
              document.getElementById('shape').style.display = "block";
            }

            //console.log("Init...");//for debugging...
          }
  
          //for recolor(showing the box with id "shape" again...) your web page...
          function Recolor()
          {
            //if it has display "none"
            if(document.getElementById('shape').style.display=="none")
            {
            //again itit...
              Initialize();
              //console.log("Recolor...IF...");
            }
          }
          
          //to draw that "shape" for the first time...
          if(FirstTime)
          {
            Initialize();
            FirstTime = false;
          }
        
          document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {             
            
             document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
            
             var endtime = new Date().getTime();

             var timetaken = (endtime - starttime) / 1000;

             document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = + timetaken + " seconds";
             //modification ....
             Recolor();

          }



       </script>

    </body>

 </html>
```

there is two function that i have made and modified the code...
I have inserted all the comments so that you can understand that what i have modified and for what...

First, there is one function...called "Initialize" for resetting all the properties again and again whenever the onclick event happens...so that you do not need to reload the page...
For that i have made all those variables global so that you can access from anywhere, whenever you need.

Second, there is one function...called "Recolor" for checking that if the id "shape" has display property none then it will call "Initialize" function again for resetting all those properties and print that "shape" again.

And ya, that "FirstTime" variable was made by me because whenever it is true..it will call "Initialize" function once so that you can use it when certain events occurs suppose, whenever you press the button you can activate those code.